# How to create mysqldump batch file?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I tried to create a batch file that can backup all my databases. My systems details:

```
OS: Server -> Windows Server 2003, Testing/local machine -> Windows Vista
Databases: MySql 5.XX
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
START C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysqldump.exe --opt -h localhost -uroot -psecret testdb | gzip > dump.sql");
```

In my code, i try to dump the "testdb" database into dumb.sql file. Can I set the name into such like : "dbname_date_time.sql"??

I answered my own question. Whoever that has the privilleges, please close/delete this question. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you have no problem with mysqldump command.

So, to manipulate date/time in bat file, you can use combinations of followings

- `echo %date%` which gives me "木 2010/01/14" in my pc
- `echo %time%` which gives me 4:02:15.28
- `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/" %%d in ("%date%") do echo %%e %%f` gives me "01 14"
- `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:" %%d in ("%time%") do echo %%d %%e` gives me "4 02" H/M
- Build file name and `rename` your `dump.sql` to new filename

Answer (score 0):

since you have mysql in your system, you can use the [date/time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions that comes with mysql

execute it using the mysql client and use a for loop to get the result. Then pluck the return result into your dump file variable name